# use gather_nd to acquire result in a loop - shapes of all inputs must match

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have this example in numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9],
              [10, 11 , 12],
              [13, 14, 15]])

res = np.zeros((5, 2), dtype=object)

for idx in range(0, len(a)-2, 2):
    a0 = a[idx]
    a1 = a[idx + 1]
    a2 = a[idx + 2]
    c = a0 + a1 + a2

    res[idx:idx + 2] = ([idx, c])

res

array([[0, array([12, 15, 18])],
       [0, array([12, 15, 18])],
       [2, array([30, 33, 36])],
       [2, array([30, 33, 36])],
       [0, 0]], dtype=object)
```

and I want to do it in tensorflow:

```
a_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
res_tf = tf.zeros((5, 2), dtype=object)

for idx in range(0, a.shape[0]-2, 2):
    a0 = tf.gather_nd(a, [idx])
    a1 = tf.gather_nd(a, [idx + 1])
    a2 = tf.gather_nd(a, [idx + 2])
    c = a0 + a1 + a2

    res = tf.gather_nd([idx, c], [idx:idx +2])
```

until line with the computation of `c` is ok.

At last line (`res`) it gives me:

```
res = tf.gather_nd([idx, c], [idx:idx +2])
                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am not sure how to receive the result.

**UPDATE**

basically, the problem lies in the fact that `[idx, c]` is of type list and trying to do :  `tf.convert_to_tensor([idx, c]`, gives :

```
InvalidArgumentError: Shapes of all inputs must match: values[0].shape = [] != values[1].shape = [3] [Op:Pack] name: packed/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> res = tf.gather_nd([idx, c], [idx:idx +2])

is syntactically incorrect. If you want to extract indices, it should rather be

```
res = tf.gather_nd([idx, c], range(idx, idx +2))
```

The latter would likely also throw an error. The indices in `range(idx, idx +2)` are higher than the indices of the list `[idx, c]`.

Also, it is not possible to create a tensor with the shape of `res` unless using `ragged tensors`. Here is a possible fix of what you're trying to do

```
a_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
res_tf = tf.zeros((5, 2), dtype=object)
l = []
for idx in range(0, a.shape[0]-2, 2):
    a0 = tf.gather_nd(a, [idx])
    a1 = tf.gather_nd(a, [idx + 1])
    a2 = tf.gather_nd(a, [idx + 2])
    c = a0 + a1 + a2
    helper = [idx]
    helper.extend(c.numpy().tolist())
    l.append(helper)

print(tf.constant(l))
```